# REPL for x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly

New to assembly here. Most dynamic languages have REPLs these days and they're great. I really want a tool like that for x86. Is there any thing open source on the table? Even if it's compiling everything from the start and running it a new or through a virtualized environment?

I just want to test argument order and see what the results look like.

Answer (score 7):

[WinREPL](https://github.com/zerosum0x0/WinREPL) is a solid go-to!

> WinREPL is a "read-eval-print loop" shell on Windows that is useful for testing/learning x86 and x64 assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Rappel also has amd64 and armv7 and v8 in addition of x86. You might want to check it out [here](https://github.com/yrp604/rappel) if you are on a Linux-based system. From its description:

> A linux-based assembly REPL for x86, amd64, armv7, and armv8

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly REPL, but [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) is a nice way to quickly see how output assembly looks for given source code.